# Add ImageView inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(new File (newBA,"/thumbanil.png").toString()));
LinearLayout Previews = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Previews);
Previews.addView(img); 
img.invalidate(); 
Previews.invalidate();
```

The idea is to create an imageview from a Drawable, inside a LinearLayout.

But it doesn't work.. What's wrong with the code ?

Comment: What happens when you spell the file `thumbnail.png` instead of `thumbanil.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a file `thumbnail.png` on the root file system of your device? i'm guessing not, as that's a read only file system.

if you want to know the root of your SD card, or external storage location, you can call [getExternalStorageDirector()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29). if you want to ensure that the external storage is available, you can use [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29). for example,

```
if (Environement.getExternalStorageState().equals(Enviroment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
  ImageView img = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
  img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(new File (newBA, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "thumbanil.png").toString()));
  LinearLayout Previews = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Previews);
  Previews.addView(img); 
  img.invalidate(); 
  Previews.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Actually, I do have a file called thumbnail.png in the folder "newBA".
The only mistake was to have misspelled "thumbnail.png" (thumbanil).